# Make constant floating label in mat input field in angular

Tags: angular

I have code where I am using form input fields so there I don't want that label should float it should be fixed on the left top corner over outline that how it look like after getting the focus. So for reference I am attaching here the video and image that what it looking and what I want actually.

**I have attached image for reference what the output I want that the floating label should always be constant up side**
[image fixed floating label](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-material-inputs-ak8dxz?file=app%2Fform-field-appearance-example.html)

**[And Added a link here for that how it is looking like currently](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-material-inputs-ak8dxz?file=app%2Fform-field-appearance-example.html)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `floatLabel` input as such:

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
```

[updated example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-material-inputs-7qlpc3?file=app/form-field-appearance-example.html)

[documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api)